# Incorrect indexes with shopify draggable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, draggable

https://www.loom.com/share/d0b06359b5e84073b944340ca4fba617?sharedAppSource=personal_library

An example is written in Vue 3
Shopify draggable emits wrong indexes on sort finished(watch loom video)

#### Logger code

```
function dragEnd(event: SortableStopEvent): void {
  console.log(event.oldIndex, event.newIndex)
  // store.dispatch('tasksModule/changeTaskOrder', {newOrder: event.newIndex, taskId})
}
```

#### Sortable custom component code

```html
<template>
  <ul ref="root">
    <slot></slot>
  </ul>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { Sortable, Plugins, SortableStopEvent, SortableStartEvent } from '@shopify/draggable'
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

interface Props {
  handleSelector: string
  draggedElement: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  handleSelector: 'li',
  draggedElement: 'li'
})

const root = ref<HTMLElement>()
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'dragStart', value: SortableStartEvent): void
  (e: 'dragEnd', value: SortableStopEvent): void
}>()

onMounted(() => {
  const sortable = new Sortable(root.value, {
    draggable: props.draggedElement,
    handle: props.handleSelector,
    plugins: [Plugins.SwapAnimation],
    sortAnimation: {
      duration: 200,
      easingFunction: 'ease-in-out'
    },
    mirror: {
      xAxis: false,
      cursorOffsetX: 5,
      constrainDimensions: true
    }
  })
  sortable.on('sortable:stop', (event: SortableStopEvent) => emit('dragEnd', event))
  sortable.on('sortable:start', (event: SortableStartEvent) => emit('dragStart', event))
})
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

### Code in the page component

```html
    <Sortable class="todo__list" @dragEnd="dragEnd" handleSelector=".todo-item__drag">
      <li class="todo__item" v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id">
        <div class="todo__item-overlay"></div>
        <AppTodoItem is-draggable @delete="deleteTask" :todoitem="task"></AppTodoItem>
      </li>
    </Sortable>
```

#### Tasks in fetching from vuex

```
onMounted(async () => {
  await store.dispatch('tasksModule/fetchTasks')
})
const tasks = computed<Task[]>(() => {
  return store.getters['tasksModule/tasks']
})
```

#### UPD: Tasks' data

[vuex state image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aasJy.png)

Comment: Hi Egor, you need to add more code from where the data is coming for you. This questions doesn't have enough information to answer

Comment: @VaritJPatel , I tried to add more info, check it

Comment: you've to add the data for the tasks array. these are the methods only.